# What does /v/qn parameter do for windows silent installers?

Tags: windows, installation, automation, automated-install, msi

[This page](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm#wp1021749) says to do a silent install you pass in the parameters `/s /v/qn`. It mentions what `/s` does - silent install - but not what `/v/qn` does.

So what does it do? Why the weird format? (on one installer I tried `/v /qn` (with a space) and it didn't work. though on another i also had to do `/S` (uppercase) and `/v/qn` didn't seem to do anything.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read the page again.

> **Passing Data to the Installation**
>
> /v : Pass arguments to Msiexec (Basic MSI and InstallScript MSI projects)
> The /v option is used to pass command-line options and values of public properties through to Msiexec.exe.

So `/v/qn` will pass `/qn` onto the embedded MSI installer.  The `/qn` is an `msiexec` switch indicating to run with no UI. You can find all `msiexec` [switches in this support article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec).

The "wierd" format is required because that is how the InstallShield command-line parser is programmed to function.  Likely, they built it this way to ensure `msiexec` switches/properties will be unambiguous on the command-line and within scripts.

Comment: ah ok, i didn't see that it was a `/v` command with a `/qn` argument and not a `/v` command followed by a `/qn` command.